# Consider the weak topology induced by all linear functionals. Is it determined on finite dimensional subspaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a vector space and equip it with the weak topology induced by *all* linear functionals $X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. I am wondering if this topology is so strong that it is determined on finite dimensional subspaces. More precisely, do we have that $C\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if $C\cap Y$ is closed for any finite dimensional subspace $Y$?

I did some computations that seem to suggest this. For example, suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a *sequence* which converges to $x$ in this topology. Then $\{x_n: x\in \mathbb{N}\}$ must be contained in some finite dimensional subspace. Indeed, if not, then we can find a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $x_{n_k}\notin \text{Span}\{x_m: m<n_k\}$ and consider a linear functional $\phi$ that sends $x_{n_k}$ to $k$, for each $k$. Then $\phi(x_{n_k})\rightarrow \infty$ and $x_n$ cannot converge to $x$. I have tried doing similar tricks for nets, but am really struggling to make it work.

For the record, since any seminorm must be continuous on $X$, we know that the topology is stronger than any norm topology on $X$. I have tried to consult Kelley's and Namioka's 'Linear Topological Spaces', but could not find anything about this exact topology. However this is such an 'obvious' topology to look at that I figure it must be known.

Comment: I don't understand how you are deducing that this topology is stronger than any norm topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what you say, this topology is not stronger than norm topologies.  Indeed, any basic open neighborhood of $0$ in this (or any) weak topology must contain a linear subspace of $X$ of finite codimension (namely, the intersection of the kernels of the finitely many functionals that define the neighborhood).  So if $X$ is infinite-dimensional, this weak topology does not contain *any* norm topology, since the unit ball in any norm topology cannot be open in the weak topology.  It follows also that the weak topology is not determined by finite-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Thanks- the part about my topology being stronger than all norm topologies must have been a catnap on my part. However, I don't see why your answer implies that the topology isn't determined on finite dimensional subspaces (in the sense I wrote down). If we found a norm such that its topology was actually stronger than my topology, then yes. But your answer doesn't imply this; my topology may still be incomparable w.r.t. all norm topologies.

Comment: Any closed set in any topological vector space has closed intersection with every finite-dimensional subspace.  So if a topology is determined by finite-dimensional subspaces in your sense, it must contain every topological vector space topology.

Comment: I am curious (and unable to resolve) how this squares with t.b.'s comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63569/27978.

Comment: @copper.hat: Unless I'm missing something, t.b.'s comment is just wrong.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks. I have struggled trying to show his comment, and yours squares with my understanding.